# A program that computes the smallest element in an array which is larger than given int x. (using recursion)

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have to write a pseudocode for a program that takes two arguments; An array and an integer. The program should print the smallest element of array that is larger than integer x. I have already written this program and it works fine. I must now re-write the code using recursion.

I have written the pseudocode that uses recursion, when I make the recursive call, I pass argument to the array [currentIndex  -1], I do that so that the program will make recursive calls and finally index can come down to zero and recursion can exit.

I want to know if recursion works in this way or is there a different method to implement recursion in this scenario.

Will the recursion call be successful if I call function recursively using seachElement(A[currentIndex -1],x)? My concern is that putting index number in the array will make it point to an individual element instead of the whole array; and if it is the right way of doing it.

```
searchElement(int A[], int x) {

n = A.length;
sum = -1;
if (A[0] == x) { sum++; return sum;}
else if (A[0] != x) {return sum;}

currentIndex = n - 1;
if(A[currentIndex] == x) {sum++;}
seachElement(A[currentIndex -1],x);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. In functional style, functions have referential transparency - they always produce the same output given the same input. This means we avoid things like mutation and variable reassignment which produce confounding results and are difficult to reason about. Here we use a secondary function with additional state parameters to keep track of the ongoing computation.

```
search (int A[], int x)
  search1 (A, x, 0, Infinity)        # 1

search1 (int A[], int x, int i, int min)
  if (i >= A.length)
    min                              # 2
  else if (A[i] > x && A[i] < min)
    search1(A, x, i + 1, A[i])       # 3
  else
    search1(A, x, i + 1, min)        # 4
```

1. Use the helper function `search1` starting an index (`i`) at `0` and the initial result (`min`) at `Infinity`.
2. When `i` is out of bounds, it's time to return the result, `min`
3. `i` is in bounds so we can check if the element `A[i]` is a new minimum. If so, recur by incrementing `i` and replacing the result with `A[i]`
4. Otherwise, `i` is still in bounds but a new minimum has not been found. Recur by incrementing `i` but keep the previous result (`min`) in tact.

---

Alternatively, if you cannot use `Infinity`, you need some other way to handle the scenario when `A` is an empty array -

```
search (int A[], int x)
  if (A.length == 0)
    null                           # 1
  else
    search1 (A, x, 1, A[0])        # 2

search1 (int A[], int x, int i, int min)
  if (i >= A.length)
    min
  else if (A[i] > x && A[i] < min)
    search1(A, x, i + 1, A[i])
  else
    search1(A, x, i + 1, min)
```

1. If `A` is an empty array, there isn't a minimum to search for. Return a `null` result.
2. Otherwise, use the helper function `search1` starting the index `i` at `1` (instead of `0`) and use the first element, `A[0]`, as the initial result. This is a safe ([inductive](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/introsml/techniques/indrec.htm)) assumption because on this code branch, `A` is known to have at least one element.